# Why is "albeit" pronounced the way it is?

Tags: pronunciation

I've previously (and am now embarrassed because of this) pronounced this word "ahl-bite" and now realize it is pronounced "ahl-bee-it." Why is it pronounced like this, and not the way I previously pronounced it?

Comment: sounds like your pronunciation has gone awry.

Comment: It is? O.o It sounds like ahl-bait when I say it...In my defense I've heard it said that way on TV. That means it's a valid alternate! Hollywood never screws stuff like that up! XP...Anyhow, I learned something. Can't think of a better reason to +1.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of two words I at first only knew from literature and had never known how to pronounce until a few years ago. Aw-ry ;)

Comment: I always wondered why people pronounce it ahl-bait and not "all be it"...

Comment: LOL. All this time Ive been pronouncing it AL-BEET.

Comment: [ɔ:l], not [a:l]. As Henry and Jon Purdy said, "albeit" derives from "all be it", and the first syllable is pronounced as it is in "all" and in other words derived from phrases starting with "all", e.g. "already".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a written shortening of *all be it*, a subjunctive set phrase roughly meaning "even if it is ..."

Answer (score 15):

*Albeit* is a contraction of *all be it*, that is, *although be it* or *although it is that*. It has no roots in German, where *ei* would be pronounced with an English long I sound.

Comment: Something about seeing it capitalized (like a German noun) also tips my mind in favor of the German pronunciation.