# Which is correct: "So far as I know" or "As far as I know"?

Tags: phrases, comparisons, so-vs-as

Which is more appropriate: "So" or "As"?

Comment: "So far as" is now a little old fashioned in most contexts; "as far as" is regular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are equally valid because *as far as* and *so far as* have exactly the same meaning in this context. However, *so far as* may be considered a slightly less formal version of *in so far as*.

> **as far as**
> to the extent that:
> *as far as I am concerned, it is no big deal*
>
> **(in) so far as**
> to the extent that:
> *it was a windless storm so far as blizzards go*
>
> [<sub>NOAD</sub>](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1246250#m_en_us1246250)

However, you will likely more often hear *as far as I know* in casual conversation. For the extremely formal, *in so far as I/we know* would not be out of place.

Answer (score 4):

"As far as I know" is the idiomatic expression I'm familiar with.

> **as far as** conj. To the degree or extent that: *They returned at nine, as
>   far as we know*. Usage Note: As far as
>   the Usage Panel is concerned, *as far
>   as* had better be followed by both a
>   subject and a form of *go* or *be
>   concerned*. *As far as* is sometimes used
>   as a preposition meaning "as for" or
>   "regarding," especially in speech, but
>   a large majority of the Panel frowns
>   upon this usage. Eighty percent find
>   the *as far as* construction in this
>   sentence unacceptable: *As far as
>   something to do on the weekend, we
>   didn't even have miniature golf.*
>   Eighty-four percent reject the
>   sentence *The Yankees are still very
>   much alive, as far as the divisional
>   race.* Further, 89 percent object to *as
>   far as* when followed by a noun clause,
>   as in *As far as how Koresh got shot,
>   we don't know yet.*

<sub>[The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009]</sub>

According to the same source "so far as" is a variation of "insofar as" :

> **so far as** conj. Insofar as: *So far as
>   I am concerned, the project is over.*

Comment: Hey! I just found another entry for http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/compound-words-what-real-compound-word-is-composed-of-most-words

Answer (score 2):

The rule I learned many years ago is that "so" follows a negative. For example, you would say, "She is as tall as her sister, but not so tall as her brother." I suspect this is one of those rules that few are taught these days and because it is rarely used correctly, the incorrect has become acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal experience* I have found "as far as" to have a lower register (is less formal) in both British and American English, is more common in American English, and is more common amongst a younger demographic.

"As far as" is also more likely to be an initial clause in a sentence than "so far as". Thus, "As far as I know, Bob is happy" over "Bob is happy, so far as I know".

They are equivalent in meaning therefore, but choice of one over another betrays, for me, certain prejudices. I also sense that "so far as" sounds slightly antiquated and is losing ground.

- that would be northern English mining town in the 1970s to the University of Cambridge, thence the last twenty-years in CT and MA, USA.