# The structure: all be it rare

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “albeit” pronounced the way it is?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/why-is-albeit-pronounced-the-way-it-is)
>   [Why have the subjunctive and indicative converged in Modern English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/why-have-the-subjunctive-and-indicative-converged-in-modern-english)
>   [When should I use the subjunctive mood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood)

Reading the [text](http://bugs.python.org/msg65513) I came across the following sentence:

> The danger, **all be it rare**, is that one may compile the 100th
>   expression only to find that one recompiles it and has to do the same
>   work all over again when it may have been done 3 expressions ago.

My question is regarding the part of the phrase highlighted in bold.

What does it mean?

My guess is that it's inversion (inverted phrase "[though] it is all rare") But I don't understand why there is *be*, not *is* (all is it rare). And it looks quite strange to me.

**Update:**

Aedia commented that it's probably a misspelling of *albeit*.

I opened an [etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=albeit) and found that *albeit* is a contraction of *al be it*, "al(though) it be (that)".

So, I still can't understand, why there is *be* (in the original phrase, from which *albeit* is derived from), not *is*?

**Update 2:**

After reading the linked questions, I still can't grasp what connotation subjunctive mood carries in comparison with indicative mood in this particular example.

In the linked questions [one of the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/why-is-albeit-pronounced-the-way-it-is/17430#17430) was that *all **be** it* = *although it **is** that*

But in the comments to this question there was a remark that **be** and **is** express different moods.

To express my question clear, I'll lay it out in the following way:

What is the difference with these structures?

- The danger, although it be rare,...
- The danger, although it is rare,...

Comment: I think this is a misspelling of [albeit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/albeit), which means *although*.

Comment: @aedia Isn't it that `albeit` appeared from `all be it`? Or their sounding the same is just a coincidence?

Comment: @aedia Why did the author write `all be it`, not `albeit`?

Comment: @aedia I opened the dictionary and found that `albeit` is a contraction of `al be it`. I'll update the question.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of the other question; the other question is asking about pronunciation.

Comment: In addition, the OP is asking about the use of `be` versus `is`. The answer to this is that `be` appears here in the subjunctive mood, while `is` is the indicative mood. The other supposed duplicate question doesn't mention this at all.

Comment: @ovgolovin -- Please don't ask another user to answer a closed question in comments.

Comment: @simchona And where should I ask him? All the linked questions don't answer completely what I want to ask.

Comment: @ovgolovin Then clearly, please, explain what you're still unsure about and users can vote to reopen the question. Answering closed questions in the comments defeats the purpose of this SE.

Comment: @simchona I made an update 2. I decided it'll be more straightforward to use 2 similar phrases: one with *is* and the other with *be*. So by juxtaposing them it's easy to grasp the idea of why subjunctive is used in the original phrase.

Comment: @ovgolovin Great. Now users can vote to open if they think it's a different question. I think it's interesting, so we'll see what happens.

Comment: @simchona Ok, Thanks! I want to ask: how do they know that they should voute? And one more question: What does `OP` mean? (it was used by phoog in the comments here).

Comment: @ovgolovin Users with more than 3K rep can vote to open/close questions (until you get to that point, you won't be able to see these votes). It takes 5 users to open or close; but a mod can close/open things by themselves. An OP is "original poster", usually.

Comment: @simchona Thanks! I would never guess myself what `OP` means (I'm not a native).

Comment: @ovgolovin Sorry to have confused you.  OP is in quite common use on stackoverflow so I assumed it was here, too.

Comment: @phoog Yeas, I saw it on StackOverflow once. But I didn't understand what it meant that time. And when I encountered it here I decided to ask. Now I know!